# Hei hayedia on second word of a smichut pair

Tags: grammar-dikduk

I recently corrected someone's use of beit hamidrash to beit-midrash, explaining that it is a smichut pair like the similar pairs, beit-knesset and beit-sefer, and that the added hei is only appropriate if it refers to a specific beit-midrash and is therefore a proper noun.

I then compared it to the use in Genesis 1 and 2 of yom hashishi and yom hash'vii, contrasting them with the same word pairs but without the hei. I suggested that without the hei, they refer to days of the week, but in Genesis 1 and 2 they are days 6 & 7 of a specific week - the week of creation - and are therefore like a proper noun, hence the hei. The trouble with that explanation is that, if so, why is there no hei for the earlier days (at least days 2 to 5)? Ibn Ezra on Gen 1:31 gives two examples of word-pairs in smichut with a hei prefixed to the second word, but I think both examples could be proper nouns. So I ask:

1. Am I right in saying that a hei should only be prefixed to the second word of a smichut pair if it is a proper noun? and
2. Why the difference in Genesis 1 between yom-sheini and yom hashishi? (I note the midrashic explanation cited by Rashi, but I am wondering if there is a grammatical explanation.)

Comment: I believe you mean 'definite noun' rather than 'proper noun'. The letter hei is a mark of definiteness.

Comment: Further, the problem with your analysis of Genesis is that yom shishi does not appear to be a semichut pair at all - it is a noun + adjective. So we would have yom sheni = lit. a second day, and hayom hashelishi = lit. the third day. Grammatically, yom hashishi (with the article on only the second word) is unexpected, but Ibn Ezra points out that there are other examples of noun + adjective with the article only on the adjective, as opposed to on both words as would be expected.

Comment: In English grammar a person's name is a "proper noun", but so is "the Mountain" if it refers to a previously named, specific mountain and therefore takes a capital M.

Comment: I believe that at least the example given by Ibn Ezra of rekiah hashamayim is a smichut pair because of the Sheva under the reish, otherwise it would be rAkia hashamayim.

Comment: @Moongazer Consider the sentences: "From the train window I noticed a mountain. The mountain was tall and covered in snow." In this case "the mountain" is definite, but not proper, and would still be marked in Hebrew with a heh.

Comment: @Moongazer regarding רקיע השמים your comment is good and occurred to me as well. However, I think Ibn Ezra's point is that the phrase (while maybe grammatically in the form of semichut) does not mean "the rakia OF the shamayim" (which would be the normal way to understand semichut and would only require a heh on the second word). Rather it means "the rakia WHICH IS the shamayim" and therefore really ought to have a heh on each word.

Comment: @JoelK In the context of your second comment, consider the use of the definite article for all days except for Bereshit 1:31 (the 6th day) and Bereshit 2:2-3 for Shabbat Kodesh. In 1:31 and 2:3, the unusual grammatical exception brings attention to distinguish those days from all others.

Comment: OK, point taken. So it seems I was wrong in assuming that those word pairs in Gen 1 are smichut pairs and they are rather cases of a noun+adjective, but what about pairs like beit midrash, beit knesset? I believe they must be smichut pairs, otherwise the first word would be bayit, not beit. Correct? Also, am I correct in saying there should be no ה prefixed to midrash unless it's a definite beit midrash, in which case it should beit hamidrash (with only one ה?) Also, do you agree that רקיעה השמים is a smichut pair, as indicated by the sheva under the ר, which would otherwise have a kammatz?

Comment: @Moongazer I agree with your analyses of beit midrash and beit knesset. Semichut. And heh on second word only, when it’s definite. Rekia hashamayim also seems to me to be semichut (Ibn Ezra’s comment on that phrase is still not clear to me)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments:

- Noun [of] noun -> noun [of] the noun.
- Noun adjective -> The noun, the adjective.

Ordinals are adjectives, thus "the third son" -- "Ha-ben Ha-Shlishi."

(Rashi, and Chazal, are bothered by the definite article in "haShishi" precisely because the grammatical trend is better without it. *Yom shlishi*, "a third day." [There had never been one before.])

Vs. "oath-of-curse", *shvuas allah*; **the** oath-of-curse, *shvuas ha-allah.*